# Is there any Time Based scheduling or functions available in WSO2 BPS(BPEL) 3.1.0

Tags: bpel, wso2, apache-ode, wso2-esb

i am working on the WSO2 BPS Server 3.1.0,

My aim is i have to write the time based condition or scheduling in BPEL ,means when i am creatng the one task and giving the some time to executing this task.

If it is not completed with in the time or it cross the given time Then alert send to user.

How can i do this in BPEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<pick>` activity is your friend. It implements the deferred choice workflow pattern, i.e. it can wait for several messages and several timers concurrently. The event that occurs first wins and the contained activity will be executed.

Comment: Hi Vanto,Thank you  i tried simple example with this <pick> activity, i am getting the following error **ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy} -  Timeout or execution error when waiting for response to MEX {MyRoleMex#4611686018427387911 [Client hqejbhcnphr8xlq9qg6p42] calling {http://wso2.org/bps/sample}Test.process(...)} java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Message exchange org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl$ResponseFuture@6ef09f92 timed out(120000 ms) when waiting for a response!** with my code **https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8538983**

Comment: The timeout happens because the initial request is not completed. I'm not sure what you intent to achieve with your process but currently it does the following: 1. an instance will be created when `process` is called. Then it waits for another invocation of `process` (in the pick). Since there is no correlation set defined, it will never be hit and the reply is never reached, which causes the timeout. You either may want to remove the receive and add the createInstance to the pick, or you want to define a correlation set to that the second request can be routed to the correct process instance.

Comment: Hi Vanto,Thanks a lot ,I am  working on simple example for how it will be use for my query,Could you please give me simple working example for this..

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/apache/ode/tree/master/bpel-test/src/test/resources/bpel/2.0/TestCorrelation1) could be helpful.

Comment: Hi Vanto,for this i set the time statically but how can i set the dynamically,means while i am running the service i need to give time dynamically, how can we achieve this in BPEL.

Comment: A duration or deadline expression can be a normal XPath expression as long as the result of the expression is a valid `xsd:date` or `xsd:dateTime` for deadlines and `xsd:duration` for durations. So you could select a properly formatted value from a variable for a dynamic timeout.

Comment: Hi Vanto,is this working for XPath1.0 or XPath 2.0.If possible can give example for this Date-time property. Thank you.

Comment: You can choose the expression language with the `expressionLanguage` attribute in `<for>` or `<until>` element. https://github.com/apache/ode/blob/master/bpel-test/src/test/resources/bpel/2.0/TestWaitUntil/WaitUntil.bpel could be helpful as well.

Comment: Hi Vanto,Is this working examples or i need to change some where else.because i am getting the error as **No input or output element has been defined for the 'testOperation' operation. An input element, an output element, or both must be defined for every operation**&&**The port 'TestPort' has no address defined. Each port must define one address.**  in wsdl test.wsdl files.  Could you please guide me.